# multiple regression log transformed how do i see initial values

Tags: multiple-regression, logarithm

I log transformed my dependent variable and all 5 independent variables to get a better fit. The dependent variable is sale price in dollars. Before I logged it, the intercept and all coefficients made sense. The intercept was 452,000 dollars. Now the intercept is really low - 3.2, which, if I exp it, is 24.97. I am completely new to this, can someone please explain how to see the values in $ and what is the reason the values are so much lower now? Or am I wrong in thinking that simply exponenting coefficients would give the correct result? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The intercept is the predicted value of the dependent variable when all independent variables have values of 0 (continuous variables) or are at their reference values (categorical variables)—*after* they have been transformed.

So after you log-transformed your continuous independent/predictor variables, their values of 0 in the transformed scale presumably represented values of 1 in their non-transformed scales. So it’s not clear that the intercept as calculated from your regression will be of much practical use. That’s probably true both for the original and for the log-transformed regressions in your case: how often do your continuous independent variables actually take on values of 0?

Working with intercepts can be tricky. It’s usually better to examine predicted values of the dependent/response variable at some “typical” values of the independent/predictor variables, for example their median values. Those should make a lot more sense both for the non-transformed and the log-transformed analyses.